# Литература про Lua и Cpp

Tags: c++, lua

Существуют ли хорошие книги или сайты по встраиванию и работе с Lua в C++

Comment: Поисковики перестали работать?

Comment: @megorit не могу найти ничего нормального, хотел бы узнать, может кто знает.

Comment: Документация же есть и готовые обертки для такого.

Comment: для желающих поделиться ценными ссылками: внесите их, пожалуйста, в описание метки [tag:lua]

Comment: @ЯрикДаркнетович возьмите книгу самого создателя lua - лучше вряд ли что-то найдете